# How to write a WCF service conforming to specific SOAP schema?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

My organization has specific guidelines on how SOAP envelop should look like.  They have specific schema (XSD) the generated SOAP message should conform to.  How to design my WCF interface to conform to this schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question on this here:
[Generate DataContract from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188909/generate-datacontract-from-xsd)

Have a look at it, I think it is what you are looking for. Bottom line is you should generate the contract from the XSD rather than hand-crafting it to make it conform when the WSDL is generated by WCF.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I think this is what I am looking for.  I will play with this and see if it works.  I also found wscfblue, an open source tool from codeplex as mentioned in comments. http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/

Comment: No prob. Link looks interesting.

Comment: Naming can also be fine tuned by properly annotating. Something like this: [DataContract(Name = "Payment", Namespace = "http://schemas.example.com")], but it is a lot of work.