# Create a DataContract for SOAP server in C#/WCF based on schema

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I have to create a SOAP service (server) written in C# and would like it to take certain XML as an input. It is a first time I have to do this. I would base my solution on http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/728/expose-wcf-service-soap-rest.

I have an XML schema for the input data. Is there a way to automatically convert the schema into [DataContract] record?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate DataContract from XSD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188909/generate-datacontract-from-xsd)

Comment: Summary of that post: use svcutil.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Simply start a Visual Studio command prompt and type:

```
svcutil /dconly mySchemaName.xsd
```

This will generate the equivalent datacontract class files for you. Syntax here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx

However you must ensure that all dependent schemas (referenced by xsd:imports) are local to the schema you are generating against.

Additionally, svcutil is very fussy about supported schema element types. See here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112(v=vs.110).aspx