# WCF Serialization issue after generating file using xsd

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

We have a pretty lengthy xsd and we generated c# DTO class using **xsd.exe**. We need to mark our classes as `DataContract` and its memebers as `DataMember` as we we want to use `DataContractSerializer` than XML.

I was able to mark classes and memebers appropriatley but while trying to run code, I am getting below `KnownType exception`, I tried adding all `KnownType` on all the classes but the errors are on similar lines. I haven't been able to find any solution for this. Can some one please suggest that how do we use `DataContract` on the file generated through xsd.exe.

> Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:

I tired svcutil and it gives me tons of errors and also doesn't generate output as expected while XSD does.

Comment: Don't use `xsd.exe` use `svcutil.exe` which is designed to auto-generate data contract classes.  See [Generate DataContract from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188909/344280).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate DataContract from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188909/generate-datacontract-from-xsd)

Comment: Thanks @MickyD ..I tried Svcutil as well but it doesn't generate properly and hence I have to stuck with xsd.

Comment: Well then possibly your XSD uses XML & XSD features not supported by the data contract serializer, such as attributes, collections without an outer container element, or polymorphism via element name rather than via `xsi:type` attribute.  So I think we need to see a [mcve] to help you, ideally an example of some XSD files for which wrong classes are generated by `svcutil.exe`, plus XML they fail to deserialize.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Punit.  I agree with dbc that you need to most a MCVE.  Any chance you can post some of the XSD that is giving you grief?

Comment: @MickyD - XSD is pretty big, it is MISMO 3.4 which is around 8 mb so won't be able to paste i guess...I didn't knew that DataContractSerializer doesn't support few xml attributes that might be a reason... Thank you for that info dbc .... Looks like only way to use is XMLSerializer to move forward....

Comment: We said _"minimal"_.  Surely you don't have problems with the entire XSD?